# WiFiNINA Reseting Arduino Nano IoT 33 When Powered Externally

Tags: power, arduino-nano-33-iot

This is puzzling me: if I power my Arduino IoT 33 Board from USB, everything runs smoothly. Now, if I power it with 5V on Vin, the board resets as soon as I call WiFiNINA's `WiFi.begin(ssid, pass)`.

Of course, power is my first suspect as I'd imagine that wifi connections draw lots of current. But what's intriguing is that the main power source is a 5V (10A) DC source that is powered by a 24V (20A) AC/DC converter. The Arduino connects to 3 I2C components (an  128x128 monochrome OLED, an INA219, and an Adafruit PWM multiplexer). There are 2 servos connected to the multiplexer. Here's the wiring diagram:

[image]

With this setup, INA219 reads 4.8V and about 100mA when both servos are moving (85mA in rest).

An important remark: the PCA9685 multiplexer has a separate V+ just to drive the servos. I was assuming that my power source is enough to drive all of this, so I didn't bother supplying a separate power source for it (btw, there's an additional 680uF capacitor on soldered the board). Just for debugging purposes I did try a separate power source for it, but the problem persists.

Here some data sheets: [24V power source](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/pd/648665?pdti=td&dl=en&lc=en-GB), [DC-DC Converter (D24-S5)](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/670/pqae50_din-2474595.pdf), [OLED](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/5297/ZJY-2828TSWIG01.pdf), [PWM Multiplexer](https://learn.adafruit.com/16-channel-pwm-servo-driver/downloads), [INA219](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ina219-current-sensor-breakout/downloads).

Finally, here's the setup code:

```
void setup() {
  delay(250);
  Wire.begin();

  // Check for the screen module
  if (!display.begin(SCREEN_ADDRESS, true)) {
    // don't continue
    while (true)
      ;
  } 

  // Check for the PWM module
  pwm.begin();
  pwm.setOscillatorFrequency(27000000);
  pwm.setPWMFreq(50); 
  // Setting servos to midpoint
  pwm.setPWM(0, 0, SERVO_START);
  pwm.setPWM(1, 0, SERVO_START);
  display_line_2 = (String) "PWM... Ok";
  printDisplay(1);
  delay(10);

  // Check for the INA219 module
  if (!ina219.begin()) {
    display_line_3 = (String) "INA219... Fail";
    printDisplay(1);
    // don't continue
    while (true)
      ;
  }

  // Check for the internal LM module
  if (!IMU.begin()) {
    display_line_4 = (String) "IMU... Failed";
    printDisplay(1);
    // don't continue
    while (true)
      ;
  }

  // check for the WiFi module:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_MODULE) {
    display_line_5 = (String) "Wifi... Failed";
    printDisplay(1);
    // don't continue
    while (true)
      ;
  } else {
      while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
      // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network:
      status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
      // wait 10 seconds for connection:
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}
```

As I said, if I comment the line `status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass)`, everything works just fine. So my question is: where the problem likely is? What would be the next step to troubleshoot it?

Comment: I'd try to move that 1000uF to Vin instead (or maybe even on 3V3 - but jumper must be shorted to be available on corresponding pin). If it doesn't help, use 9V/12V Vin or skip the INA219. Check Vin and 3V3 rails with the oscilloscope (MPM3610 has operation voltages between 4.5-21V).

Comment: Also DC-DC mentions minimal output current 0.5A, and who knows what is happening when you are taking less.

Comment: Interesting: moving the 1000uF to INA219's Vin didn't change the end result, but immediately gave me a less noisy power bus (I know it because the OLED doesn't flicker anymore), meaning that my wiring is indeed screwed up. I just bought a cheap oscilloscope and it should arrive tomorrow. But considering it's my first oscilloscope, I reckon I'll need some training.

With regards to the minimum of 0.5A, that's not a problem as there are other 5V devices being powered by it and it currently measures 2A.

Thanks!